# Which version of Insight toolkit has support of libxml2?

Tags: libxml2, itk, cmake-gui

I have created a ITK solution from Insight toolkit version 4.5.2 using CMake-GUI on windows 10. Now while using ITK in my own project(created using CMake-GUI), I am getting following error:-

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'itklibxml2.lib'

I searched my ITK source directory but was unable to find the above library

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/f338f8a0ce5fe94e8a02cd3e7e9c2a728e9c1a00/Utilities/README.itklibxml2) say that *The itklibxml2 library is only included in ITK if the cmake variable ITK_USE_LIBXML2 is set to "ON".*

But this is for ITK version 3! I suppose your own project was written for ITKv3. If there is `ITK_USE_LIBXML2` in [ITK 4.5.2](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/tree/01661ccf9923b89873806a2de6a8571badaf6668) try turning it on. Otherwise you will have to modify your project to not use that library. Start by removing `itklibxml2` from your `CMakeLists.txt`.